awk throwing syntax error only when used as alias
I have run the following command successfully, to calculate the total CPU usage using the ps command:
ps -A -o pcpu | tail -n+2 | awk '{sum+=$1}END{print sum}'


However, when I tried to create an alias for this command
alias totalcpu="ps -A -o pcpu | tail -n+2 | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}'"

awk threw the following error when I tried executing the alias (totalcpu):
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near } 

I tried executing the alias in the same shell, so that I don't need to update the .bashrc file.

alias is for commands. Bind entire pipelines to functions.

$1 gets expanded when the alias is defined, not when it is used.

FWIW, you don't really need to discard the header line: ps -A -o pcpu | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}'

take a look at my mquote (magic quote) which can help deal with this kind of quoting work.

Forget aliases. They are remnants from the past (to allow unmaintained old stuffs to still work); when shells did not have functions. Aliases are full of quoting and escaping traps. Always prefer functions. Functions declarations can be put in ~/.bashrc or whatever interactive shell session initialization and replace all those clunky aliases.
This is all you need instead of an alias :
totalcpu(){ ps -Ao pcpu|awk '{s+=$1}END{print s}';}


Thanks, it worked. I thought aliases are meant for a executing a single command and functions for executing a block of commands.

Others have already explained it, but to demonstrate what's happening, use an echo.
Since you are wrapping the entire pipeline in double quotes, it is being interpolated at parse. The single quotes are inside the doubles, so are not preventing the interpolation of $1, which probably does not have a value when setting the alias - almost certainly not one you would want.
$: echo "ps -A -o pcpu | tail -n+2 | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}'"
ps -A -o pcpu | tail -n+2 | awk '{sum+=} END {print sum}'

Now you can see what is actually being set as the alias and executed, and why it's a syntax error. That's why Matthias' solution fixes it - he is explicitly protecting the $1 from being read as a variable when the alias is set, so that it still exists in the code awk sees when run.
(As an aside, another solution would be to set your bash environment's $1 with the value you want inserted, but his approach is very confusing and I don't recommend it...still, demonstrated below.)
$: echo "ps -A -o pcpu | tail -n+2 | awk '{sum+=\$1} END {print sum}'"
ps -A -o pcpu | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}'

$: set -- '$1' # make value of $1 a literal "$1" - works, but don't
$: echo "ps -A -o pcpu | tail -n+2 | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}'"
ps -A -o pcpu | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}'


Léa Gris is absolutely correct, however; there is very rarely a time when a function is not preferable in practically every way to an alias.
The "purpose" of a function is essentially the same as an alias - to encapsulate some behavior that you want repeatable, maybe with less typing and/or thinking, though it also lets you incorporate a significant bit of logic.
Functions require a lot less effort to manage problems like the one you had here. They can take arguments, accept inline variables, and use recursion, much like a "real" script, none of which work very well with an alias.
Yes, you can write your alias so that all arguments come after, but that's not always enough. You can set variables ahead of time, but sometimes you don't want them to stay. With a function you can use it the same way, but you have other options.

As @Biffen already pointed out, $1 is expanded too early. Fix for your problem:
alias totalcpu="ps -A -o pcpu | tail -n+2 | awk '{sum+=\$1} END {print sum}'"


To be technically correct, $1 should never be expanded by the shell (as it is an awk variable)

@Fravadona : yes and no, the shell has correctly expanded it (given the syntax provided) since the entire alias was defined by double quotes, so awk's pair of  single quotes don't protect jacksxxx. I usually make mine more hideous like alias=' something | awk '\''{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }'\'' '  — that way everything is fully protected by single quotes so sigils inside awk don't need to be escaped, at the expense of overall readability
